# How to force Host-Only adapter to retrieve an IP from the VirtualBox DHCP server

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, dhcp-server

I have a Linux RHEL guest running on a VirtualBox VM, the host machine OS is Windows 7.

I'm trying to link both by a Host-Only network, but I can't reach one machine from another, and I guess that this is because the host machine host-only adapter not linked properly with the VBox network manager, first of all it's unable to retrieve a valid IP from the VBoxDHCP server.

Everytime I restart the host-only adapter I get the same ip provided by Windows 7 somehow

```
inet addr:169.254.17.104 Mask: 255.255.0.0
```

However, my VBoxDHCP server is not configured on that range.

```
➤ ./VBoxManage.exe list dhcpservers
NetworkName:    HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
IP:             192.168.56.100
NetworkMask:    255.255.255.0
lowerIPAddress: 192.168.56.101
upperIPAddress: 192.168.56.254
Enabled:        Yes
```

I've tried to fix this removing and then creating the adapter again with

```
VBoxManage.exe hostonlyif remove
VBoxManage.exe hostonlyif create
```

However the Linux guest machine works fine.

```
[root@ivs-dev] # dhclient -v eth1
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.1.1-P1
Copyright 2004-2010 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Listening on LPF/eth1/08:00:27:b6:7c:63
Sending on   LPF/eth1/08:00:27:b6:7c:63
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x3c540d01)
DHCPOFFER from 192.168.56.100
DHCPREQUEST on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3c540d01)
DHCPACK from 192.168.56.100 (xid=0x3c540d01)
bound to 192.168.56.102 -- renewal in 502 seconds.
```

Hope you guys can give me a hand with this, because this worked before and suddenly it's not working anymore. Any idea will be more than welcome.

Regards

Comment: 169.254.*.* is the [autoconfiguration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv4) address range. So your Windows client is using autoconfiguration instead of DHCP. Turn autoconfiguration off, turn DHCP on (whatever that is called in Windows 7).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, enable / disabling the auto-ip is not the solution, since auto-ip happens because there's an issue when trying to get an IP.

Comment: It suddenly started to work. I'm not able to determine what was the cause of the problem, so I'm pretty sure that it will happen again, if I found the reason / solution to my problem I will post the answer.

Comment: Well, yes, the point is not to disallow autoconfiguration (which you can't), the point is to make it use DHCP in the first place. I'm no Windows 7 expert, though, so I can't tell you what went wrong when it tried to use DHCP. Just make sure to enable it. And if the Linux guest works fine, the problem must be in the Windows guest, not somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well looks like you can't configure the VBoxHostOnly adapter properties from the classic Windows dialog.

I had to do it from the VBox / File / Preferences / Network / Host-Only Networks, then select your adapter and set the properties from there.

And sometimes VBox is not able to reload properly the configuration changes so maybe you may need to reboot your computer after configuring adapters / networks / DHCP / NAT servers.